# .htaccess masking URL for subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url-masking

Our site's sub-domain reading.domain.com has the content that we want people to see but the URL should be domain.com/reading.

I'm not an expert in URL rewriting but I tried to edit htaccess, but it only redirects the page.

We're using siteground, does hosting company has something to do with their apache configuration to make this work?

Thank you very much.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^reading/$? domain.com/reading/ [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: First, anytime you use `R` flag, that's is an automatic `redirect`. Which is what its for. 2nd, the only way to do that is using a proxy. You can try replacing the `R` with `P` flag. Mod_proxy will have to be enabled already.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, thanks for the insight @Panama Jack, [P] = it real does need proxy, [NC] case-sensitive, [L] use this rule one time.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^reading/?$ http://reading.domain.com/ [P,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```